# Codeigniter undefined variable: title , PHP error is encountered

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on simple application consisting of simple form. My code really works fine in local environment. But when i uploaded it on a live server gives an error, unable to fetch database fields and i think there is an error in my model.

Here is my model class

```
 class Model_get extends CI_Model
    {

    function getData($page) {   

    $query = $this->db->get_where('ci_tbl', array('page' => $page));

    print_r($query->result());
    return $query->result();
}

}
```

Here goes my view

```
<div id="content">

<?php


foreach ($results as $row) {
    $title = $row->title;
    $para1 = $row->para1;
    $para2 = $row->para2;

}

echo heading($title, 1);

?>
    <p><?php echo $title;?></p>
    <p><?php echo $para1;?></p>
    <p><?php echo $para2;?></p>
</div>
```

My controller goes as

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->home();
}

public function home() {

$this->load->model('model_get');

$data['results'] = $this->model_get->getData('home');

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('nav');
$this->load->view('main_content',$data);
$this->load->view('footer');


}


public function about() {
$this->load->model('model_get');

$data['results'] = $this->model_get->getData('about');

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('nav');
$this->load->view('about_page',$data);
$this->load->view('footer');

}
```

Comment: Did you checked your connections and so on ?

Comment: Where and how you define `$results`?

Comment: @panther $results is the data passed from the controler

Comment: $result is a variable that is contains fields from database... and Guilherme Ferreira, how to make sure and check db  connection in CI

Comment: @panther $result is a variable that is contains fields from database

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually return the results of the query:

```
//print_r($query->result());
return $query->result();
```

At the moment you've commented out `return $query->result();` and you're just printing the result. The controller calling the model isn't going to get that information and therefore isn't passing through to the view.

Also check that the database connection is correct if moving from local to a public environment.

Comment: actually i used print_r() to print the query result.. i've uncommented but still have the same error

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/about_page.php

Line Number: 5

Comment: @RizwanSunny Your view file is not getting the results variable. Try print_r($results) on top of your view and see if it gives you any output.

Comment: @HarigovindR i've tried it returns Array(), nothing inside this array... :(

Comment: @RizwanSunny Try print_r($data) in your controller inside the about page method and see whats being returned.

Comment: @BeatAlex i've made changes in config file and set the parameters according... what else need to be set in connection..

Comment: I mean make sure that you have the right username, password and database name in `database.php` and you're connecting to the right table in your model. @RizwanSunny

Comment: @BeatAlex If thats the issue then he should be getting different errors right.? Like table not found or column not found etc?

Comment: @RizwanSunny Try printing out the query results in model as well as controller make sure that your query is executed and output is obtained

Comment: @HarigovindR, dear i've pointed out(echo) result in both of the model and controller, now whole page disappeared and the errors tooo..

Comment: @BeatAlex, All credentials in database.php are correct and even i've inserted some more data inside database tables.. why does it say variables not defined..

Comment: @RizwanSunny First print the results in model and give an exit from the model. Dont echo results do a print_r.

Comment: @HarigovindR print_r function returns an empty Array(), nothing inside parameters.. shows this additional error too.....                                    Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @RizwanSunny If print_r() in your model returns empty array then your query is returning no values. That is why your variable is showing undefined

Comment: @HarigovindR, Brother, check my database.php file..                                                   
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ashyanaa_ci_db';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

Comment: @HarigovindR, the same code works fine in local environment ..but throws error while i live it..

Comment: @RizwanSunny Try changing your hostname to that of your server

Answer (score 0):

Actually you had an error

```
foreach ($results as $row) { 
$title=$ row->title;
       ^^^^
```

It should be

```
$title = $row->title;
         ^^^
```

You need to update your query within model as

```
class Model_get extends CI_Model {  
  function getData($page) {    
    $query = $this - > db - > get_where('ci_tbl', array('page' => $page));
    return $query->result_array();
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems you didn't check my answer at all

Comment: Its correct but, while pasting here is being shown as.  error still  not resolved :(

Comment: Are you getting an array within your controller its seems you were not returning value from your model

Comment: When Gilsha edited the post they made this mistake. In the original question this problem didn't exist.

Comment: @Naredra Sisodia i've uncommented return line.. but the error still persists

Comment: @RizwanSunny I've updated my answer along with the updated models code you can check it that ways